# $V=U_1\oplus ...\oplus U_n \iff \dim(V)=\dim(U_1)+...+\dim(U_n)$ and $V=U_1+...+U_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $$\text{if }\dim(V)=\dim(U_1)+\dots+\dim(U_n)\text{ and } V=U_1+\dots+U_n\text{, then }V=U_1\oplus\dots\oplus U_n $$

If $n=1$, it's obvious. Set $W=U_1+\dots+U_{n-1}$ and suppose $\dim(W)=\dim(U_1)+\dots+\dim(U_{n-1})$. By the induction hypothesis, we have that $W=U_1\oplus\dots\oplus U_{n-1}$. Let's prove that $V=W\oplus U_n$, given that we have that $V=W+U_n$ and $\dim(V)=\dim(W)+\dim(U_n)$. Therefore $$\dim(W\cap U_n)=\dim(W)+\dim(U_n)-\dim(W+U_n)=\dim(V)-\dim(V)=0.$$
Therefore, $$V=W\oplus U_n=U_1\oplus\dots\oplus U_n.$$

Does it work ? My big doubt is about the fact that I implicitly used $$(A\oplus B)\oplus C=A\oplus B\oplus C,$$
and I'm not really sure if it really holds.

Comment: Of course it works. The best way to be sure is to prove $(A\oplus B)\oplus C=A\oplus B\oplus C$ (and it's really not complicated).

Comment: In order to proceed by induction you need to be able to prove that $$[\dim(V)=\dim(U_1)+...+\dim(U_n)\quad \text{and}\quad V=U_1+...+U_n]\implies [\dim(U_1+...+U_{n-1})=\dim(U_1)+...+\dim(U_{n-1})]$$